# Need help with an exercise on a sequence with integrals.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let $(I_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined by $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, I_{n}= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan^n(x)dx.$

I proved that $(I_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ decreases.

I'd like to prove that $\forall n \geq 2$, $\frac{1}{2(n+1)} \leq I_{n} \leq \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$.

Can anyone help me get started please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe if you integrate by parts you can express $I_{n+2}$ in terms of $I_{n+1}$ or 
 $I_{n}$. A similar thing works for integral of $\sin^n x$.

Comment: I already proved that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, I_{n}+I_{n+2}= \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: I started the same way you did, @Pablito. Then I proceeded to try induction: It worked fine for the upper inequality but not for the lower. :(

Comment: I edited the title. In English we say *sequence* here.

Comment: I went looking for other solutions and I found this: [How to show the inequality for $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan^n(x) dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368340/how-to-show-the-inequality-for-int-0-pi-4-tannx-dx)

Comment: Thanks a lot that's perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like $\tan(x) \ge x$ so

$$ I_n \ge \int_0^{\pi/4} x^n \,dx = \frac{1}{n + 1} \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{n+1}. $$

And $(\pi/4)^{2 + 1} < 1/2$. Then you do something similar for the upper bound.

Comment: Oh yeah it works but I can't find any relation for the upper bound though :/

Comment: @Pablito I thought of using $(4/\pi)x \ge \tan(x)$ which gives $1/(n+1) \ge I_n$ but this isn't quite sharp enough. You can use the relation $I_n + I_{n + 2} = 1/(n+1)$ to get $I_{n+2} \le 1/(n + 1) - 1/2(n+1) = 1/2(n+1)$. This is what you want but it's only for $n + 2 \ge 4$ so you need to calculate $n = 2$ and $n = 3$ separately. This is what Ted mentioned in the comments.